# Threading Consumers in a Blocking Collection

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, .net-4.5

I have windows service that on a timer event adds items to a blocking collection and then creates a thread for each item in the queue to be processed.I am using `CompleteAdding()` to make sure the queue is not empty but I am still not sure if for ex
    1. If this method is thread safe
    2. Does `GetConsumingEnumerable()` leave the consumer threads waiting for more work       indefinitely? (I want the threads to exit when processing is 
complete)
    3. Is this solution ideal for a production environment?

```
dt = GetValues()

            If Not dt Is Nothing Then

                Dim value As Integer

                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

                    BlockingColl.Add(value)
                Next
                BlockingColl.CompleteAdding()

             Try
                    'Create consumer threads

                    While BlockingColl.IsCompleted = False

                        For Each value As Integer In BlockingColl.GetConsumingEnumerable()
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                      If (value IsNot Nothing) Then
                                                          ProcessValue(value)
                                                      End If
                                                  End Sub)
                        Next
                    End While
            Catch e As InvalidOperationException
               throw ex
            End Try

            End if
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a complicated way to write `Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows, dr => ProcessValue(dr))`.

Probably, you need to limit the degree of parallelism as well because the heuristics of `Parallel.ForEach` tend to create crazy amounts of threads.

Comment: So you are saying I don't need a concurrent queue or blocking collection?

Comment: What would you need them for?